# Create a new Feature Type and / or Layer on GeoServer using REST API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to create new tables on GeoServer using the REST API. All the layers I want to publish are visible in the feature type section which looks like this:

[image]

when I use then 'get' i would also get the configuration of the feature type.
however there are no layers created.
The problem seems to be, that it cannot read the columns from the sql. I get an error :

*StatusCodeError: 500 - "the SimpleFeatureType swh:testlayer does not contains the configured attribute ogc_fid. Check your schema configuration"*

the config looks like this:

```
"featureType": {
    "name": "TestLayer",
    "nativeName": "TestLayer",
    "namespace": {
        "name": "TestGS",
        "href": "https://test.com/geoserver/rest/namespaces/TestGS"
    },
    "title": "TestLayer",
    "keywords": {
        "string": [
            "features",
            "TestLayer"
        ]
    },
    "srs": "EPSG:4326",
    "enabled": true,
    "advertised": false,
    "metadata": {
        "entry": {
            "@key": "JDBC_VIRTUAL_TABLE",
            "virtualTable": {
                "name": "TestLayer",
                "sql": "SELECT ogc_fid as id, * FROM public.testlayer\n",
                "escapeSql": false,
                "keyColumn": "ogc_fid",
                "geometry": {
                    "name": "wkb",
                    "type": "Geometry",
                    "srid": 4326
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "store": {
        "@class": "dataStore",
        "name": "TestGS:TestGS",
        "href": "https://test.com/geoserver/rest/workspaces/TestGS/datastores/TestGS.json"
    },
    "maxFeatures": 0,
    "numDecimals": 0,
    "overridingServiceSRS": false,
    "skipNumberMatched": false,
    "circularArcPresent": false,
    "attributes": {
       "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "useroop",
                "minOccurs": 0,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": true,
                "binding": "java.lang.Long"
            },
            {
                "name": "ogc_fid",
                "minOccurs": 1,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": false,
                "binding": "java.lang.Integer"
            },
            {
                "name": "gpxtrackoop",
                "minOccurs": 0,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": true,
                "binding": "java.lang.Long"
            },
            {
                "name": "tsstart",
                "minOccurs": 0,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": true,
                "binding": "java.lang.Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "tsend",
                "minOccurs": 0,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": true,
                "binding": "java.lang.Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "tsupdate",
                "minOccurs": 0,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": true,
                "binding": "java.lang.Integer"
            },
            {
                "name": "wkb",
                "minOccurs": 0,
                "maxOccurs": 1,
                "nillable": true,
                "binding": "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point"
            },        
    },
    "projectionPolicy": "FORCE_DECLARED",
    "nativeBoundingBox": {...
    },
    "latLonBoundingBox": {...
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please add the actual calls and endpoints you are using

Comment: I updated the question!

Comment: please use **text** not pictures, and don't "redact" workspace and layer names, they are public anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a conflict between the sql view name and the original table name (`"TestLayer"` and `"testlayer"`). Try changing the `"nativeName"` and `metadata/entry/virtualTable/name` parameters to be more different from the table name used in the sql `FROM` statement.